# Defining custom Accuracy score: real changes contained in predictions. Numpy implementation?

Tags: pandas, numpy, performance, scikit-learn, multilabel-classification

I am running a multi-label prediction model. As a performance measure, I am checking whether the top `N` predictions from my model contain the real cases where `y=1`.

For example, if my model's top predictions for a data point are Yellow(90%), Green(80%), Red(75%) while reality is Green and Red, I count it as a "Correct" prediction, while a measure such as [(Exact) accuracy](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html#sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score) would count it as incorrect.

Below is my implementation, which has a somewhat realistic example of large X and y matrices (with many columns). I need to find an implementation (or a completely different solution) which runs faster.

**Reproducible example (which runs too slow, ~2 min) below:**

```py
from scipy.sparse import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
import time

np.random.seed(14)

## Generate sparse X, and y
X = random(100_000, 1000, density=0.01, format='csr')
y = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice([0, 1], size=(100_000, 10)))
# Define no change as 0 in all rows
y['no_change'] = np.where(y.sum(axis=1) == 0, 1, 0)

dt = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=15)
dt.fit(X, y)

# Print precise accuracy -- truth must precisely match prediction
print(f"Accuracy score (precise): {accuracy_score(y_true=y, y_pred=dt.predict(X=X)):.1%}")

# Get top n predictions based on probability (in case of equality keep all)
def top_n_preds(row, n_top):
    topcols = row[row > 0].nlargest(n=n_top, keep='all')
    top_colnames = topcols.index.tolist()
    return top_colnames

start = time.time()
# Retrieve probabilities of predictions
pred_probs = np.asarray(dt.predict_proba(X=X))
pred_probs = pd.DataFrame(pred_probs[:, :, 1].T, columns=y.columns)

# Find top 5 predictions
pred_probs['top_preds'] = pred_probs.apply(top_n_preds, axis=1, n_top=5)
# List all real changes in y
pred_probs['real_changes'] = y.apply(lambda row: row[row == 1].index.tolist(), axis=1)
# Check if real changes are contained in top 5 predictions
pred_probs['preds_cover_reality'] = pred_probs.apply(lambda row: set(row['real_changes']).issubset(set(row['top_preds'])), axis=1)

print(f"Accuracy present in top n_top predictions: {pred_probs['preds_cover_reality'].sum() / y.shape[0]:.1%}")
print(f"Time elapsed: {(time.time()-start)/60:.1f} minutes")
```

Comment: when you apply `top_n_preds` on `pred_probs`, the `np_change` column is also there, should not you exclude it from the values of top n predictions per row?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Apologies, I did not notice your comment. The idea is that `y['no_change']` is another variable (class) which takes value of 1 if all else is 0. So it's okay if it can take on positive probabilities in `pred_probs` and come up as one of the top predictions (`top_n_preds`).

Comment: @Dudelsten, Ok, must `'top_preds'` and `'real_changes'` columns be kept in the final `pred_probs` dataframe, or they are just auxiliary (for calculating accuracy score) ?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Just auxiliary, accuracy score is key, so that I can tune parameters based on it in reasonable time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 consecutive `.apply` calls in your case produce significant overhead and delay.
To boost the performance I suggest to make a single traversal on paired datasets: `pred_probs` and `y.values == 1` (one-time obtained filtering dataset for *`real_changes`* columns).
Another most expensive and time-delaying part is calling `pandas.Series.nlargest` on `pred_probs` rows.
Despite one may think that it can be replaced by `numpy.argpartition`, that's not totally true. There might be cases when the amount of filtered values of some `pred_probs` row will be less than `top_N`, that breaks `np.argpartition()` call.
 Even more notable is a special case `Series.nlargest(n=top_N, keep='all')`, the one you use, allows keeping duplicates so that the amount of the resulting sample would be greater than `top_N`.
To somehow imitate that behavior I use combination of `np.sort` + `np.in1d` + `np.where`.

My new version aggregates accuracy picks/marks for the final accuracy score in about **2.5** seconds.

```
top_N = 5

def agg_accuracy_picks(preds, y, top_n):
    """Aggregate accuracy picks/marks"""
    p_cols, y_cols = preds.columns, y.columns

    for p_row, y_row in zip(preds.values, y.values == 1):
        # top N values with all duplicates
        top_values = np.in1d(p_row, np.sort(p_row[p_row > 0])[-top_n:])
        top_cols = p_cols[np.where(top_values)[0]]

        yield set(y_cols[y_row]) <= set(top_cols)


start = time.time()
# Retrieve probabilities of predictions
pred_probs = np.asarray(dt.predict_proba(X=X))
pred_probs = pd.DataFrame(pred_probs[:, :, 1].T, columns=y.columns)

pred_probs['preds_cover_reality'] = list(agg_accuracy_picks(pred_probs, y=y, top_n=top_N))

print(f"Accuracy present in top n_top predictions: "
      f"{pred_probs['preds_cover_reality'].sum() / y.shape[0]:.1%}")
print(f"Time elapsed: {(time.time() - start): .1f} seconds")
```

Sample output:

```
Accuracy score (precise): 0.4%
Accuracy present in top n_top predictions: 3.5%
Time elapsed:  2.5 seconds
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thank you very much!! I confirm it's miles faster than previous algorithm and gives identical results.

Comment: @Dudelstein, you're welcome, thanks for the interesting challenge.